# Best approach to problem, is VLOOKUP correct?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Good Afternoon,

I am looking for the best way to approach this task, I have 4 different shows and want to know which customer has been to each and likewise which has not.

Is vlookup with a nested IF the best approach?

[image]

For example, I want if to show Yes or No

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe.

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(ISNUMBER(x)*(x>0), "yes", IF(x="", "no", x)))
 (QUERY(A2:B, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A label B' '")))
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks, will have to research how this works! As cannot see any reference in the formula to the type but it correctly fills it.